# How to remove "YouTube video Player'" hover message in Chromium fullscreen

Tags: streaming-video, chromium, kiosk, youtube

I'm using a Raspberry Pi for a Digital Signage project for university.

I have a small issue with a hover hint box (I don't know the correct name) showing when Chromium plays YouTube Fullscreen.

I had to change some flags to get media working:

- GPU Rasterization Override
- Override software rendering list

This is the command that runs at startup to launch Chromium:

`/usr/bin/chromium-browser --kiosk --disable-restore-session-state --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/foyer/presentation/`

Autoplay-policy was what fixed videos not playing automatically.

YouTube Video player hover message on Chromium on Pi OS. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rzuq.jpg

I'm hazarding a guess that the cursor defaults to the middle of the screen and that's why it's appearing, as moving the mouse makes it dissapear.

Really appreciate any help given. TIA

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by installing unclutter and incorporating this command into my .sh file:

```
/usr/bin/unclutter -idle 5 -grab -root
```